# Pie Chart por linha de código c#

Tags: c#, gráfico

Preciso criar gráficos em tempo de execução, conforme o usuário pede. Achei um código no site **[TI4Fun](http://www.ti4fun.com/alexandre/Rotinas/C%23?r=Co7yOkOuG5Q[[ti)** 
nele o cara consegue alterar as propriedades do *chart* do jeito que eu quero. O problema é que preciso criar um novo, quando uso:

```
var cht_MacroOndas = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
this.Controls.Add(cht_MacroOndas);
```

Consigo criar o *chart*, mas não posso editá-lo. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu sei que já faz um tempo que você postou e me avisou via face mas só agora eu pude realmente olhar isso.

Neste seu exemplo você está criando um novo gráfico e adicionando na coleção, você poderia verificar se já existe uma instância da classe na coleção Controls e pegá-la mas tentei fazer algumas experiências e é muito chato então minha sugestão é a seguinte.

Um objeto que você adiciona na coleção mantem sua referência desde que o escopo em que ele foi criado ainda esteja ativo, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte.

1. Declarar a variável no escopo do formulário

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart cht_MacroOndas;
   ```
2. Verificar no momento da atualização do gráfico se a variável já não foi instanciada e só criar uma nova caso precise

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           if (cht_MacroOndas == null)
           {
                   cht_MacroOndas = new Chart();
                   this.Controls.Add(cht_MacroOndas);
           }

           ConfigurarChat(cht_MacroOndas);
   }
   ```

Lembre-se de limpar as coleções ao usar o objeto chart anterior, eu coloquei esse método ConfigurarChat apenas para deixar claro que nesse ponto você configuraria o gráfico, nele você teria que zeras as coleções Series, Legends, ChartAreas ou qualquer outra que você adiciona ao preencher os dados.